# How to perform an animate function first and then apply

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have written code to flip and then increase the width and size of an image:

```
 $(obj).animate({"left": "-=40px","opacity": "0.65"},"slow");
 $(obj).animate({"height":"600px","width":"320px"},70);

 alert('1');
 //$(obj).css("-webkit-backface-visibility","hidden");

 $(obj).css("-webkit-transform-style","preserve-3d");
 $(obj).css("-webkit-transition","all 1.0s linear");
 $(obj).css("transform-style","preserve-3d");
 $(obj).css("transition","all 1.0s linear");

 $(obj).css("-webkit-transform","rotateY(180deg)");
 $(obj).css("transform","rotateY(180deg)");
 alert('2');
```

First, I want to resize and then perform flip animation code. Here, first `css()` is executed and then the image is resized. How do I delay `css()` here?

Comment: place your CSS manipulation code inside animation callback, and it should work fine.. i guess..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
$(obj).animate({"left": "-=40px", "opacity": "0.65"}, "slow");
$(obj).animate({"height":"600px", "width":"320px"}, 70, function () {
    //Called after animation is complete
    $(this).css({
        "-webkit-transform-style": "preserve-3d",
        "-webkit-transition": "all 1.0s linear",
        "transform-style": "preserve-3d",
        "transition": "all 1.0s linear",
        "-webkit-transform": "rotateY(180deg)",
        "transform": "rotateY(180deg)"
    });
});
```

Comment: Won't the above execute the css calls before the first animation is done? First animate has a timer of "slow", and the second call is "70".

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use the complete callback from the animate function:

```
$(obj).animate({"left": "-=40px","opacity": "0.65"},"slow");
$(obj).animate({"height":"600px","width":"320px"},70, "", function () {

    //$(obj).css("-webkit-backface-visibility","hidden");
    $(obj).css("-webkit-transform-style","preserve-3d");
    $(obj).css("-webkit-transition","all 1.0s linear");
    $(obj).css("transform-style","preserve-3d");
    $(obj).css("transition","all 1.0s linear");

    $(obj).css("-webkit-transform","rotateY(180deg)");
    $(obj).css("transform","rotateY(180deg)");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also be able to use the [.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) function of jQuery to delay secondary actions until after all animations are finished. This method works for multiple animations, which callbacks won't.

So place your .css calls into the promise().done function as shown below:

```
$(obj).animate({"left": "-=40px","opacity": "0.65"},"slow");
$(obj).animate({"height":"600px","width":"320px"},70);

$(obj).promise().done(function () {
    // css stuff here
});
```